# How to exclude single package from npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am currently using the `"typescript": "^3.8.1"` package in my package.json file.

As part of the CI deployment process, I would like to exclude the typescript package when running npm install.

I have tried the following command:

`npm install --only=prod --omit=typescript`

However, I am still seeing the typescript package in the `node_modules` folder, and the size of the `node_modules` folder remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily change the package.json by filtering out `typescript`:

```
mv package.json _package.json && grep -v typescript _package.json > package.json && npm i --only=prod; mv _package.json package.json
```